# #PowerBI _ How to make the array and calculation for this multi subjects

Tags: powerbi

Below is the data set. it's without Total line. and row is as date.
[image]

and would like to make this in the power bi as below.
(Forecast - Act)/Forecast for category and Total for each date.
[image]

I've tried with SUM and calculate DAX but didn't reach to the answer.
also wonder if my array in original sheet is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. table unpivot & pivot in PowerQuery, see as below gif:
   [image]
2. use "Matrix" table visual to show data, see as below gif:
   [image]

Comment: What a great answer..,!! ssoooo Thank you, I've searched for the answer for two days

Comment: okay! then will you mark my answer as accept then it will show "√" or click top inverted triangle so i can get points! 